# fedora tomcat log file path

Tags: configuration, logging, tomcat, fedora

My log file is inside:

```
kamil@localhost tomcat$ grep "logs/" ./*
./log4j.properties:log4j.appender.R.File=${catalina.home}/logs/tomcat.log
```

my CATALINA_HOME is

```
kamil@localhost tomcat$ sudo grep "CATALINA" ./*
...
./tomcat.conf:CATALINA_HOME="/usr/share/tomcat"
```

that above suggests that my log file is hare, and there it's:

```
kamil@localhost tomcat$ sudo ls /usr/share/tomcat/logs/ | grep .out
catalina.out
```

So why can't I start server:

```
kamil@localhost tomcat$ sudo tomcat start
/usr/sbin/tomcat: line 30: /logs/catalina.out: No such file or directory
```

Comment: How do you start your Tomcat-instance? My immediate guess is that the CATALINA_HOME-variable is never read and set.

Comment: Have you tried `catalina.base` - something like /var/lib/tomcat - instead of `catalina.home`? Isn't there a `logs` folder under catalina.base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `$CATALINA_HOME` in tomcat.conf is not read by the tomcat-process. And when you start Tomcat it sets its logpath to `$CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out` which translates to `/logs/catalina.out` when `$CATALINA_HOME` is not set.

The Tomcat startup-script is configured to read environment variables from a file called `setenv.sh` in the `bin/` directory.

Make sure that `$CATALINA_HOME` is set in this file and you should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

You searched within /usr/SHARE/tomcat/logs, its looking for the file in /usr/SBIN/tomcat/logs. Those are two different locations. I'm not an expert on tomcat, but I think you can specify CATALINA_HOME within your catalina.sh file.

Comment: Note that `/logs/catalina.out` is an absolute path and *not* a relative path and it does not search for the file in `/usr/sbin/tomcat/logs`.